# amazon web services passing facebook token

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I'm using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.2.1 and I'm using Amazon Cognito iOS SDK together with Facebook SDK to provide user authentication.I have integrated Facebook SDK to my app and I am able to get authentication token from Facebook.I am following the AWS official documentation to add the login functionality to my app via Facebook.

To provide the Facebook access token to Amazon cognito we have to implement AWSIdentityProviderManager but I am not able to do that.

My IdentityProviderManager is as follows which is a different file in the same project:

```
import Foundation
import AWSCore
import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin

class FacebookProvider: NSObject, AWSIdentityProviderManager {
    func logins() -> AWSTask<NSDictionary> {
        if let token = AccessToken.current?.authenticationToken {

            return AWSTask(result: [AWSIdentityProviderFacebook:token])
        }
        return AWSTask(error:NSError(domain: "Facebook Login", code: -1 , userInfo: ["Facebook" : "No current Facebook access token"]))
    }
}
```

and following is the code which I have written in the AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import AWSCore
import FBSDKCoreKit


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var obj = FacebookProvider()
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USWest2, identityPoolId: "MyIdentityPoolId", identityProviderManager: obj)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USWest2 , credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continueWith(block: { (task) -> AnyObject? in
            if (task.error != nil) {
                print("Error: " + task.error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            else {
                let cognitoId = task.result!
                print("Cognito id: \(cognitoId)")
            }
            return task;
        })

        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        return handled
    }

}
```

What should I do to provide Facebook access token to Amazon Cognito?
Please provide solution.

Comment: Hi, you could use AWS Mobile Hub and use it to configure Facebook with an Identity Pool. AWS Mobile Hub will also generate a sample app specific to your configuration and demo login with Facebook. It will also have instructions to integrate it with your existing app.

Comment: I have to do it through AWS Cognito.Any solution for that?

Comment: Mobile Hub does that using AWS Cognito as well. You can see the link in this answer for doing it directly: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=252306&tstart=0